# Limit users to upload 800x800 and less than 1.5mb wordpress media

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, dimensions, restrict

Hello i am trying to set some restrictions in my wordpress website. I would like to limit my users for maximum upload size of 1.5mb but also restrict them of uploading anything bigger than 800x800 or anything smaller than that.. In that way everything will look equal and organized. If you know any other simpler way than coding it into wordpress please let me know.

Thanks to whoever solve this for me!!

Comment: And what have you tried to do so far then? You're going to need to code this...

Comment: I dont mind coding it, but i don't know what to code or where. I only tried playing with wordpress setting-media but didn't work. i also found a plugin that limits the size but it doesn't limit the dimensions.. so coding it is. if you can help me i will appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

**To set your dimension restrictions:**

Add this to your **parent** theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter','tc_handle_upload_prefilter');
function tc_handle_upload_prefilter($file)
{
    $img=getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
    $minimum = array('width' => '800', 'height' => 800');
    $width= $img[0];
    $height =$img[1];

    if ($width < $minimum['width'] )
        return array("error"=>"Image dimensions are too small. Minimum width is {$minimum['width']}px. Uploaded image width is $width px");

    elseif ($height <  $minimum['height'])
        return array("error"=>"Image dimensions are too small. Minimum height is {$minimum['height']}px. Uploaded image height is $height px");
    else
        return $file; 
}
```

Note about functions file and child themes:

> Unlike style.css, the functions.php of a child
>   theme does not override its counterpart from the parent. Instead, it
>   is loaded in addition to the parent’s functions.php. (Specifically, it
>   is loaded right before the parent’s file.)

**To set your filesize restrictions:**

Create a text file with the following contents:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1500K
post_max_size = 1500K
```

Save it as `php.ini` and place this in the root of your Wordpress directory. This will chang the PHP settings only for your Wordpress site.

Comment: I did find that but it does only one part of my question.. So i deleted it because if i am going to code may as well code the whole thing instead of only dimensions..

Comment: Yeah I just read that in your comment after I posted that as an answer.

Comment: Do i need to add anything else in my code since i am using a child theme? or just create a functions.php file in directory and add the code? thanks

Comment: The functions file of a parent is not overridden by a child, so this means you'll need to add it to the parent functions file. And update the code if it gets updated and removed. See my note in my answer.

Comment: which means if i update wordpress in the near future this code will be removed.. correct? If the answer is yes is there a way to prevent that? adding hooks or whatever they are called?

Comment: I get this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /home4/hobbitcy/public_html/wp-content/themes/dokan/functions.php on line 540

Comment: Okay, so on line 540 you're missing a closing bracket (may be caused by code further up the file)